# Using a lot of threads in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am currently working on a script that plays music from mid files to an game using keystrokes, it uses 1 thread for each note, so that means one music with 1k notes have 1k threads.

It works for some small mid files, but it is obvious that it doesnt on large files...

Is there are any way to have this year amount of threads without dropping an error? Anyway to increase max threads?

Answer (score 0):

Does an orchestra have one musician per note?  No.  Neither should your program have one thread per note.

Just issue the "play sound" requests to the operating system and move on.  No need to wait for them to complete.

There's no reason to have more than two threads for this: one for reading data and buffering, and one for triggering the sounds.  Many programs would even combine them into a single thread.

Comment: well i was using multithreads for i could play the note exactly at the time its suposed to by time.sleep ,  i have no ideia on how to do that without multithreading, considering that i can't play notes at the exactly same time by the game issue... Thanks for the quick awnser.

Comment: Aaaaugh! For the rest of my life, whenever I see a band playing on stage, a voice in my head is going to whisper, "Cool! They're _re-using_ those musicians."